# Clojure with IntelliJ/Cursive: "run" task not available

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, leiningen, cursive

How can I run a Clojure project from IntelliJ/Cursive? The `run` task doesn't show up under `Tasks` in the `Leiningen tool window` despite the fact that the `help` task lists `run` as an available task. There doesn't seem to be a way to add tasks to the window, either.

Additional info:

- I used the Windows installer to install Leiningen
- I followed [this](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/index.html) Cursive tutorial to set up (created project with `lein new`, then imported it to IntelliJ)
- I set up a "Hello World" according to [this](https://clojurebridge.github.io/community-docs/docs/getting-started/helloworld/) guide, but running core.clj from the regular menubar doesn't produce output

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run `lein run` you can create a new run configuration: menu `Run` -> `Edit Configurations` and add new Leiningen configuration providing `run` in the arguments field.

When you just want to run a namespace you can right click on it in the project browser window and choose `Run <your selected namespace name>` menu item.

Comment: Usually when I create a new configuration it's available in the drop down menu, however the Leiningen "Run" configuration didn't show up anywhere.

Comment: "providing run in the arguments field" - thanks that's the bit I was missing!

Comment: I can't believe you actually have to do this for every single project. People create projects and never run them? am I missing something?